# How to return a pointer as a function parameter

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm trying to return the data pointer from the function parameter:

```
bool dosomething(char *data){
    int datasize = 100;
    data = (char *)malloc(datasize);
    // here data address = 10968998
    return 1;
}
```

but when I call the function in the following way, the data address changes to zero:

```
char *data = NULL;
if(dosomething(data)){
    // here data address = 0 ! (should be 10968998)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you really using C or are you using C++ (some comments indicate you talk about C++ references).

Comment: i didnt mark it as c++ because i didnt know it mattered and people often complain "thats not c++ thats c" because i am using malloc()...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're passing by value. `dosomething` modifies its local copy of `data` - the caller will never see that.

Use this:

```
bool dosomething(char **data){
    int datasize = 100;
    *data = (char *)malloc(datasize);
    return 1;
}

char *data = NULL;
if(dosomething(&data)){
}
```

Comment: oh damn... i see, a pointer to the pointer... but wasnt there some other way to do this? ive seen functions that take a pointer without & in it, is it possible to convert my function work that way? (i like it without & since its less error prone)

Comment: You could do `char * dosomething(char *)` and return the new pointer.

Comment: but i want to return the bool value from the function, i meant if i could call the function `dosomething(data)` instead of `dosomething(&data)` any way? maybe in c++?

Comment: in c++ yes - then use `bool dosomething (char * & data)` - pass by reference

Comment: Does the caller have a responsibility to deallocate the pointer in this case? (delete data or some such)?

Comment: @BadPirate yes It has to deallocate the memory at the address that is in the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int changeme(int foobar) {
  foobar = 42;
  return 0;
}

int  main(void) {
  int quux = 0;
  changeme(quux);
  /* what do you expect `quux` to have now? */
}
```

It's the same thing with your snippet.

*C passes **everything** by value.*