# fwrite function writing data wrongly

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to read a specified piece of data from one file and write it into a specified offset of a second file, but I have a problem. The `fwrite` function for some reason isn't writing the data read from the first file. Instead, it writes a non-printing character (possibly null character, idk) at the offset of the second file. Here's the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    if (argc < 7)
    {
        print_usage(args[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (argc > 7)
    {
        printf("Too many parameters\n");
        
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if (geteuid() != 0)
    {
        printf("This program requires root privileges\n");
        
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    unsigned long offset;
    unsigned long size;
    char *partpath;
    char *filepath;
    
    int c;
    
    for (c = 0; c < argc; c++)
    {
        char *arg = args[c];
        
        if (strcmp(arg, "-o") == 0)
        {
            offset = strtoul(args[++c], NULL, 0);
            
            continue;
        }
        
        if (strcmp(arg, "-s") == 0)
        {
            size = strtoul(args[++c], NULL, 0);
            
            continue;
        }
        
        if (c == argc - 2)
            partpath = args[c];
        if (c == argc - 1)
            filepath = args[c];
    }

    printf("offset: %lu (0x%lx)\nsize: %lu (0x%lx)\npartition: %s\nfile: %s\n", offset, offset, size, size, partpath, filepath);
    
    flash_part(partpath, offset, filepath, size);

    return 0;
}

void flash_part(const char *partition_path, unsigned long offset, const char *file_to_flash, unsigned long size)
{
    log("Opening files...");
    FILE *partition = fopen(partition_path, "r+");
    
    FILE *flash_file = fopen(file_to_flash, "r");
    
    log("Jumping to partition offset...");
    // jump to partition offset
    fseek(partition, offset, SEEK_SET);
    
    // start flashing chunk by chunk

    log("Start flashing...");
    void *chk = calloc(1, sizeof(void*));
    size_t count = read_chk(flash_file, chk);
    
    printf("readed %d bytes\n", count);
    
    write_chk(partition, chk,  count);
    free(chk);
    
    while (count >= CHK_SIZE)
    {
        chk = calloc(1, sizeof(void*));
        count = read_chk(flash_file, chk);
        
        write_chk(partition, chk, count);
        
        free(chk);
    }
    
    log("Partition flashed, closing files...");
    
    fclose(partition);
    fclose(flash_file);
}

size_t read_chk(FILE *file, void *out)
{
    char *chk_data = calloc(CHK_SIZE, 1);
    
    size_t readed = fread(chk_data, 1, CHK_SIZE, file);
    
    out = chk_data;

    return readed;
}

void write_chk(FILE *file, void *data, unsigned int size)
{
    fwrite(data, 1, size, file);
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: You wrote a function named `write_chk` that does not, in any way, check the results of the write. Seems like a fun opportunity to miss errors.

Comment: This does not do anything `out = chk_data;` In C, function arguments are passed as copy. You do not change the value seen by the caller.

Comment: You claim, the issue is with calling `fwrite`. What did you do to make sure, reading is OK? Did you step through your code in a debugger and check that all variables hold proper contents? If not, you should start doing this when facing incorrect results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a pointer as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286453/how-to-return-a-pointer-as-a-function-parameter)

Comment: You should probably open the files in binary mode. It doesn't matter if you are on a Unixy system, but at least on Windows it does, so it's pragmatic to add that `b` to open ode.

Comment: Don't print a usage statement in response to an error.  Print an error message.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: What do you mean by that? They only print the usage message when they receive too few arguments (which is an error in usage). Many of their error messages are going to `stdout` when they should go to `stderr`, but I don't see any `print_usage` occurring for non-usage reasons.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I mean that a usage statement should never be printed in response to an error, even if it is a usage error.  It is far more useful to get a brief message along the lines of "too few arguments (-h for usage)".  If you spew usage (which inevitably grows to be 9 screenfuls long), then the user has to wonder exactly what they did wrong. If you print a brief description of the error, there's less room for confusion.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: As written, they don't have switch support at all, so `-h`/`--help` can't be used for full usage. When it's production code, yeah, short usage statements for misuse, long ones only on request, but this clearly isn't production code.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Best practice is best practice.  If you follow bad practice in non-production code, it inevitably creeps into production code.  And there are far too many instances of usage statement spew in production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `read_chk` is completely broken. You accept a pointer from the user, ignore it, allocate a completely different thing, populate *that*, *replace* the pointer received (rather than copying data to where it points; assigning to a pointer changes *that pointer*, and not the copy of the same pointer the caller holds), so from the point of view of the caller, nothing happened; it passed a pointer to a zeroed buffer, you didn't put anything in the buffer, so it's still got the original zeroes (the "caller" might notice eventually when the program crashes from the progressive memory leak from `read_chk`'s `calloc` calls that are never `free`d, but that's not useful feedback really).

Essentially, nothing is wrong with your writing, it's accurately writing out all the zeroes you told it to write.

The solution depends on the value of `CHK_SIZE`; if it's the same as `sizeof(void*)`, then just get rid of `chk_data` and directly pass `out` to `fread` in its place. If it's larger, you do the same thing, but change the caller to `calloc` using `CHK_SIZE` instead of `sizeof(void*)`. Either way, `read_chk` changes to look like:

```
size_t read_chk(FILE *file, void *out)
{    
    return fread(out, 1, CHK_SIZE, file);
}
```

leaving it to the caller to provide a `CHK_SIZE` buffer to use. The caller could skip the `calloc` entirely too; a stack array of `char buf[CHK_SIZE];` could be used and remove the need for dynamic allocation and freeing.

Comment: my intention doing "out = calloc(1, sizeof(char*)" is allocating a pointer that will point to the data that I'll alocate soon on read_chk, CHK_SIZE = 512 btw, thx for replying I'll test it right now

Comment: @CarlosHenrique, re-read what you just wrote, as it fully encapsulates the logical error that this answer calls out: you allocate space for something that you are later going to allocate [more; different] space for.  Since you know in advance how much space you are going to need, I agree with this answer that you would save yourself a lot of trouble by skipping *all* the dynamic allocation, and just declaring an array of the required size.  You don't need dynamic allocation to have or use pointers.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique: If that's the goal, you'd need to have `read_chk` receive a `void**`, not a `void*`, change the definition of `chk` outside the class to `void **` (maybe `char**`, can't recall if that would match prototype), change the assignment to `*out = chk_data;` (note dereference prefix), pass `*chk` to `write_chk` instead of passing `chk`, *and* add an extra `free(*chk);` before you call `free(chk);`. And repeat said changes all over the code base.

Comment: In short, multiple nested dynamic allocations are pretty complicated and nonsensical when your code is already *mostly* written to work with a single layer of allocation, and you don't need dynamic allocation at all; you could just have the caller declare and pass `char buf[CHK_SIZE];` (no dynamic allocation needed), and have `read_chk`/`write_chk` use it directly, no `calloc`s (maybe a `memset` instead if you want to allow incomplete reads to pretend the rest of the data is zero), no `free`s. If the choice is "complex, slow *and* brittle" vs. "simple, fast and robust", it's not a hard choice.

Comment: yeah ! I was thinking about using pointer to pointer to handle this but your answear works well thx